# How to replace a value to the current payload in mule

Tags: mule, decode, clob, payload

I have retrieved some values from the Database. Out of which one field is of type CLOB and that needs to be decoded. I have fetched the value and decoded it successfully. Now I need to set the decoded value to a particular field of the payload. Could someone help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Expression component` to modify payload -

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[payload.root.myprop = 'newvalue']]></expression-component>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `<set-payload value="#[decodedClob]" />` but if you want to set the payload to a particular field you need know how to do that, I mean which type is your payload.